# Mass assignment and Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create new client using form but I can't do it. The problem is: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Here is some code:

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name']

Client::create($request->all());
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that `name` has no value when you are trying to create a new client. Make sure your HTML form input is named `name`. The input name must match the name of the column in your database table. This is most likely your issue.

**UPDATE**

1. Edit your client migration to this `$table->string('name')->nullable();`
2. Run `php artisan migrate:refresh`

You will now be able to create a new client without requiring a name.

Comment: I have column name, input is named name, but I have no text in input  because I don't want it. And I can't create client with null form.

Comment: @SuperProgrammer Just so I am clear, you want to be able to create a new client without them having to input a name, correct?

Comment: yup, I have also another inputs but I want to create even if that is empty. Only ID will be there then.

Comment: then make your 'name' column nullable

Comment: @SuperProgrammer Okay. That is easy. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your migration, you have to set your name field to nullable:

```
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Or set a default() value:

```
$table->string('name')->default('');
```

Then you have to run migrations to update your table.